# Non linear regression

Tags: matlab, regression, non-linear-regression

I am trying to do a non linear regression to find the constants Is and n with the least square curve fitting.This is the formula `Is(exp(1).^(V/26.*n))`
And this is my code

```
fun = @(n,Is)Is(exp(1).^(V/26.*n));
x0 = [0,14];
x = lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,V,I)
```

It retruns the following

> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in @(n,Is)Is(exp(1).^(V/26.*n))
>
> Error in lsqcurvefit (line 202)
>               initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html

> Function you want to fit, specified as a function handle or the name of a function. fun is a function that takes **two inputs: a vector or matrix x, and a vector or matrix xdata.** fun returns a vector or matrix F, the objective function evaluated at x and xdata.

In your case your `fun` gets only your parameters to fit, not your data. I suggest changing it to

```
fun = @(X,V) X(2)*(exp(1).^(V/26.*X(1)));
```